# Which swim lane should i move a task into when a task is done but new designs come in

Tags: agile

This is an overall methodology agile question .

If my devs have completed tickets and the QA team has moved them to Done .

If all new creatives come in for those existing tickets what is the best way to handle that .

My thought was to move them back to "To-Do" and start them all over ...

Comment: No, done is done. Should be a new task that's added to backlog and migrated to complete.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Scrum then it would be usual to start a new ticket in this situation. The reason is that we count the points in 'Done' and use the total to calculate the velocity of the team. If a new story is added then you need to count the work done originally and also the new work.

I would also expect some questions to be asked in the retrospective about the timing of the new creatives. It may have been better not to have started on the original story until the new creatives were in.

Answer (score 0):

First we should not start a story if the story is not defined clearly. We need to use Backlog and sprint planning meetings refine user stories.

If this is a new change, then it should be a new item, since you have set the task to Done based on "Definition of done".

To create a relationship between items you can link those two items.  If you keep on using the same task you will end up with issues in adding estimations and actual, which will effect your planning for the next sprin